# Ensure figcaption width never exceeds image width

Tags: html, css

I'm creating CSS for an article-style page. The article is a series of paragraphs wrapped at a fixed width — in the example below, 300px — interspersed with occasional `figure`s. Each `figure` has an `img` and a `figcaption`, and is allowed to be up to 400px wide. Note that the real widths are larger, but I've scaled them down for ease of viewing in the example.

The problem I'm having is that I would like each `figcaption` to be no wider than the `img` preceding it, even if the `img` is narrower than its enclosing 400px-wide `figure`. When the `img` is 400px wide or wider, this isn't a problem, because it gets scaled down to 400px wide and the `figcaption` is also 400px wide, as in Image 1 in the example below. But when the `img`'s inherent width is less than 400px, both the `figure` and the `figcaption` remain at 400px and the caption extends past the image's edges, as in Image 2 in the example below.

Things I've tried:

- Setting `display: inline-block` on the `figure`
- Setting `width: fit-content` on the `figure`
- Setting `width: calc(foo)` on the `figure`, but I'm not sure what to put in `foo`

It seems like what I want is for the `figure` to "shrink-to-fit" the image size, but I understand that's not really a well-supported concept in the CSS model. There must be another way to do this that I don't grok.

### Related questions

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41427894/1292061), which seems pretty similar, suggests using `display: inline-table`, which seems like the wrong tool for the job. But perhaps it isn't?
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35136547/1292061) suggests using `display: table` as well, though there's also an odd `width: 1%` which also seems questionable.

```css
p {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

figure {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

figure>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>This is the first paragraph of an article. This is the first paragraph of an article. This is the first paragraph of an article.</p>

<figure>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/500/300" />
  <figcaption>
    Image 1: This image is wider than the figure max-width of 400px, so it occupies the figure's full width, and its long caption is limited to the width of the image.
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<p>This is the second paragraph of an article. This is the second paragraph of an article. This is the second paragraph of an article. </p>

<figure>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/350/300" />
  <figcaption>
    Image 2: This image is narrower than the figure max-width of 400px, so it occupies less than the figure's full width, and its long caption is wider than the image. <b>This is the problematic case.</b>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: `width: 0;
    min-width: 100%;` to figcaption